# Why My Visual Studio Not Showing Any Text?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when open my project. It doesn't show any text.
Here the screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you see the Solution Explorer (its on the View Menu) keys are: CTRL+W, CTRL+S ?

Comment: You haven't actually opened anything so what would you expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tried to open project file from file explorer. open your existing project from visual studio itself

Comment: @Trafalgar As JayV suggested above. Open `View > Solution Explorer` and you should see all your files there.